# Disable std::optional's forwarding constructor

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding, qdatastream, stdoptional

I've extended QDataStream with a template conversion operator so that the datastream loads from itself and converts to any supported type, as such:

```
class ConvertibleQDataStream : public QDataStream
{
public:

    using QDataStream::QDataStream;

    template <class T>
    explicit operator T ()
    {
        T t;
        *this >> t;
        return t;
    }
};
```

And one can add support to types not supported by QDataStream by overloading operator >>, as such:

```
template <class T>
ConvertibleQDataStream&
operator >> (ConvertibleQDataStream& ds, std::vector<T>& v)
{
    //Called for std::vector's.
    return ds;
}
```

The idea is to be able to construct non-default constructible classes directly from a stream, like this:

```
class Bar
{
public:

    Bar(ConvertibleQDataStream&);
};

class Foo
{
    int mInt;
    std::vector<double> mVector;
    Bar mBar;

public:

    Foo(ConvertibleQDataStream& ds) :
        mInt(ds),     //Calls operator >> for int and converts to int 
        mVector(ds),  //Calls operator >> for std::vector<T> and converts to std::vector<T>
        mBar(ds)      //Plain constructor call 
    {}
};
```

This works great except when a member is a `std::optional`. `std::optional`'s forwarding constructor is called in stead of `ConvertibleQDataStream`'s template conversion operator:

```
template <class T>
ConvertibleQDataStream&
operator >> (ConvertibleQDataStream& ds, std::optional<T>& o)
{
    //Never called :(
    return ds;
}

class Qux
{
    std::optional<Bar> mOptional;

public:

    Foo(ConvertibleQDataStream& ds) :
        mOptional(ds) //calls Bar::Bar(ConvertibleQDataStream&) rather then operator >> for std::optional<T> due to forwarding c'tor.
    {}
};
```

Can one disable `std::optional`'s forwarding constructor? Or another workaround for this.

Comment: What's wrong with `Foo(ConvertibleQDataStream& ds){ ds >> mOptional; }`?

Comment: @alterigel: A class might have non-default constructible members. These have to be initialised in the member-initialiser list. As the order in which data is extracted from the stream is important some things cannot be moved to the constructor body.

Comment: @Unimportant do you mean that you want  `ConvertibleQDataStream::operator T()` to be called with `T=std::optional<Bar>`?

Comment: @alterigel Yes, it works for all other types but forwarding constructors get in the way.

Comment: standard conversion got preference over the user-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a problem with option, this is a problem in your design where mOptional is constructable from ConvertibleQDataStream.

C++ conversion rules can be a *nightmare* and should likely be avoided in this case by providing explicit get operators.

```
class ConvertibleQDataStream : public QDataStream
{
public:
    using QDataStream::QDataStream;

    template <class T>
     T Get() const
    {
        T t;
        *this >> t;
        return t;
    }
};

class Qux
{
    std::optional<Bar> mOptional;

public:

    Foo(ConvertibleQDataStream& ds) :
        mOptional(ds.Get<std::optional<Bar>>())
    {}
};
```

Comment: They aren't that  much of nightmare, allowing user-defined conversion to be preferred would cause `#define true false` kind of chaos.

Comment: With perfect forwarding constructors they cause all sorts of crazyness, even in the stl.

std::optional<bool> behaves particularly badly:

std::optional<bool> x; // empty
std::optional<bool> y(x); // what do you think happens here?

Comment: not sure what do you mean. they are both empty... because x was empty? Doesn't it use a copy-constructor? Other constructors are explicit or conditionally explicit.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie y actually constains false.

std::optionl is implicitly convertable to bool.